# Can't connect to Lightsail Managed Database - (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to connect to a Lightsail managed database from a Lightsail instance in the same region using PHP's mysqli extension, but am getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

My script is very basic and looks like this:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "ls-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com");
define("DB_NAME", "xxxxxxx");
define("DB_USER", "xxxxxxx");
define("DB_PASS", "xxxxxxx");
$db= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME,3306);
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I've checked `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and found that it was my Lightsail instance's private IP address.
- I've tried with and without `Public mode` turned on in the database's `Networking` tab
- I've been able to connect to it successfully using MySQL Workbench
- I've tried turning on `VPC Peering` for my chosen region in the Account section of Lightsail

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is phpMyAdmin running on a Lightsail instance? Have you tried using the database's IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: @DavidG Yes the PHPMyAdmin is running on my Lightsail instance via the cPanel installation running on it. I don't know how to find out the IP address of the database instance. I've checked carefully on each screen and can't see one listed anywhere.

Comment: Is the database in the same region as your Lightsail instance? If not try enabling "public mode" on the database to see if that works.

Comment: Hi Mike. The instance and the database are both in the same region and public mode is also already on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it might help anyone, the cause of my issue was that port 3306 was blocked by my host-level firewall (ConfigServer firewall) despite being open at network firewall level.

Once I opened added 3306 to CSF's list of allowed ports this error went away.

Comment: How to open 3306 in Lightsail Database

Comment: I didn't need to do that. It was the default port.